# iPhone rings once and phone is open to caller

Tags: iphone

My iPhone rings once and the caller is there. How do I make it ring until I answer it?
I’ve tried looking for a solution in settings.

Comment: Are you saying your phone automatically accepts incoming calls?

Answer (score 4):

There is an "Auto-Answer Calls" setting in:

Settings > General > Accessibility > Call Audio Routing

Navigate there and turn it off if it is enabled.

Answer (score 1):

On iPhone 8, go to Settings -> General -> Accessibility -> call audio routing, set to automatic. Tap and check automatic if not set. When you get here, then make sure auto-answer calls is set to off. Voila! No more automatic answer after 4 seconds or some time less than carrier set time for auto answer in voice mail (usually 30 seconds).

Comment: Please edit your post with the proper capitalization and punctuation.